# How do I fix an application bundle after editing its contents?

Tags: macos, applications, ventura

I am wondering if there's any way to "fix" a signed application bundle after editing its contents. Say, I edit `Contents/Info.plist` or another file. Naturally, this invalidates the code signature, but even if I use `codesign` to remove the signature on the app (either before or after editing the bundle) or indeed resigning the bundle with my own certificate, it seems to corrupt the application, and I get some nasty (and apparently random) process exit error when I run the application.

Is there any way to resolve this? Is `codesign` corrupting the bundle, or is there something else I need to change/recompute in the bundle after modifying its contents, apart from the code signature? I don't mind "recreating" the entire bundle even, if that allows the application to run correctly, but have no idea how to do that.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, **you** can't code sign an app that you don't own/build yourself. Not being a programmer myself I don't know the exact procedure but I do believe  the app is signed when it is compiled/built.

Comment: It would seem a fairly large hole in the security if you could just re-sign an altered app.

Comment: @benwiggy Why? It should be no security hole at all, given I'd be resigning it with my *own* certificate. Cryptographically, altering the content being signed just means you need to resign it. If you don't care exactly which certificate it's resigned with (e.g. you're fine with self-signing it), it's perfectly possible.

Comment: @SteveChambers I think that might be the case from the perspective of the APIs that Apple offers, but cryptographically there can't exist a guarantee for that without other provisos, as far as I'm aware.